# Writing and reading nfc cards in ndef message in windows form application

Tags: c#, windows, nfc, ndef, acr122

I don't know if this is possible because I have been searching for hours with no leads. I want to make a C# program on desktop that is connected to the ACR122u reader. I want to be able to read and store the NDEF message value as a string for processing. Is this even possible if so where do I begin?

Note: I have looked and examined the examples supplied with the ACR122u reader but none have worked for me or even displayed the message I stored from a third part application.lease do help

Comment: What does this have to do with Android?